# Why var a is undefined? Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I have this code. It creates an object with x and y field. I want to add a method, which creates new object with additional width and height fields. But despite my tryings it keeps returning undefined. What is wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLNjH/)

```
function $ (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    return this;
}

$.prototype.$ = function (x, y) {
    this.width = x - this.x;
    this.height = y - this.y;

    return this;
}

var a = $(10,10).$(30,30);
alert(a.width);
```

Comment: When you mention the word "it", to which part of the code are you referring? :)

Comment: I could not find the correct word (I'm not so good in english, sorry :P)

Comment: you show the result of a.width. what about a? is it also undefined?

Comment: No problem; just trying to clarify... because "it" could be any part of your code ;)

Comment: @DanielS. a is defined as an Object. it works now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `new` before `$`; This works:

```
var a = new $(10,10).$(30,30);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var a = (new $(10,10)).$(30,30); //You need new
alert(a.width);
```

Also it might not be a good idea to have an instance function of a class to have the same name as the class -- it is a little confusing.

---

Here is how you can do what you want to do with 2 "Point" objects (as asked for in the comments):

```
var Point = (function(){
    var Point = function(x, y) {
        this.width = x;
        this.height = y;
    }
    Point.prototype.removePoint = function(point) {
        return new Point(point.width - this.width, point.height - this.height);
    }

    return Point;
})()

var a = new Point(10,10);
var b = new Point(30,30);

var c = a.removePoint(b);
alert(c.width);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/d3fx7/

Comment: @AreWojciechowski it is redundant and confusing. It might be a good idea to give actual names to functions :-)

Comment: If we are talking about naming now, as well, you may want to avoid using `$` for a function (or object) if you start using [certain](http://jquery.com/) [JavaScript](http://prototypejs.org/) [libraries](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollar) out there, as well.

Comment: @summea a few libraries use `$`, not only jQuery :-P

Comment: @Neal And that is why I wrote the plural form of "library"... ;) *(and now the links are updated)*

Comment: like Point(10,10).Point(30,30)? i wanted to name it as short as possible. and it's only for practise :P

Comment: @AreWojciechowski Try `removePoint` and pass another point object as opposed to just passing x and y values.

Comment: @Neal I'm not sure that I understand. So how it would look?

Comment: @Neal Oh, I think I caused some confusion here. :P `Point(10,10).Point(30,30)` is not a substraction! It creates a vector  from `Point(10,10)` to `Point(30,30)`.
_(I think that code was unclear and I'm sorry for that :P)_

Comment: LOL whatever you want. But you should still use the method in my answer. whatever you decide to name the function @AreWojciechowski it will still do what you want :-)

Comment: thanks and sorry for messing up :P (I'm quite new, so sorry :P)